# how can i construct a new array from a large API by deleting some elements and adding values

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

This is the fake data that I've made for testing:

```
const data =[

    {
        country: 'US',
        city: 'NY',
        population: 1000
    },
    {
        country: 'CA',
        city: 'TOR',
        population: 1000
    },
    {
        country: 'US',
        city: 'LA',
        population: 1000
    },
    {
        country: 'CH',
        city: 'BEI',
        population: 1000
    },
    {
        country: 'CA',
        city: 'VAN',
        population: 1000
    },
    {
        country: 'CH',
        city: 'SHANG',
        population: 1000
    },
]
```

Let's just pretend that we're working with an API with 100+ countries and many more cities. How do I make a new array out of this array that looks like this:

```
const finalData = [
    {
        country: 'US',
        population: 2000
    },
    {
        country: 'CA',
        population: 2000
    },
    {
        country: 'CH',
        population: 2000
    },
]
```

So basically grouping them based on their countries and adding the population from cities with the same country.

Comment: this question is incomplete  //where do you get the data for the population size of the given country?

Answer (score 2):

You can build a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) using [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), where the map is keyed by the `country` property. If you encounter a country which is already in the map, you can add to its value storing a summed population count. If the country doesn't exist in the map, you can add the current population as the value with the new country as the key. You can then use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to convert the Map to an array, where you can provide a mapping function to map the entries to objects:

```js
const data = [ { country: 'US', city: 'NY', population: 1000 }, { country: 'CA', city: 'TOR', population: 1000 }, { country: 'US', city: 'LA', population: 1000 }, { country: 'CH', city: 'BEI', population: 1000 }, { country: 'CA', city: 'VAN', population: 1000 }, { country: 'CH', city: 'SHANG', population: 1000 }, ];

const res = Array.from(data.reduce(
  (m, {country:c, population:p}) => m.set(c, (m.get(c) || 0) + p), new Map
), ([country, population]) => ({country, population}));

console.log(res);
```

If your goal is to remove the `city` key and keep all other keys (rather than just keep the `country` and `population` keys only), then you can use the following, which will remove the `city` key, but keep all other keys:

```js
const data = [ { country: 'US', city: 'NY', population: 1000 }, { country: 'CA', city: 'TOR', population: 1000 }, { country: 'US', city: 'LA', population: 1000 }, { country: 'CH', city: 'BEI', population: 1000 }, { country: 'CA', city: 'VAN', population: 1000 }, { country: 'CH', city: 'SHANG', population: 1000}, ];

const res = Array.from(data.reduce((m, {country, city, population, ...r}) => {
  const curr = m.get(country) || {country, population: 0, ...r};
  return m.set(country, {...curr, population: curr.population + population, ...r});
}, new Map).values());

console.log(res);
```

Comment: sorry sir, it worked fine but i'm having a hard time trying to understand  `(m.get(c) || 0) + p)` part can you explain it a little bit

Comment: @Ihopemyenglishisgood sure. `m.get(c)` will either return a number which we previously stored in the Map, or `undefined` if the key `c` is not in the Map. For example, if it returns `3` the `(m.get(c) || 0)` will evaluate to the number `3`, which `p` (the current population of the current object) is then added to. However, if `m.get(c)` returns `undefined`, then `(m.get(c) || 0)` will evaluate to `0`, which `p` is added to. So `(m.get(c) || 0) + p` just says if the key `c` is already in the map, grab its value and add `p` to it, if it is not in the map, set it to have the value of `p`

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array#reduce`.

```
let finalData = data.reduce((acc,curr)=>{
     let obj = acc.find(({country})=>country===curr.country);
     if(obj){
         obj.population += curr.population;
     } else {
         acc.push({country:curr.country,population:curr.population});
     }
     return acc;
}, []);
```

Comment: @hev1 - array.find needs a loop to find the element. instead we can use map or object for constant read operation.

Comment: @front_end_dev That's true; this solution is not the most efficient. I would edit my answer, but Nick Parsons has already added an answer using a Map.

Answer (score 0):

An approach using find method of an array

```js
const data =[

    {
        country: 'US',
        city: 'NY',
        population: 1000
    },
    {
        country: 'CA',
        city: 'TOR',
        population: 1000
    },
    {
        country: 'US',
        city: 'LA',
        population: 1000
    },
    {
        country: 'CH',
        city: 'BEI',
        population: 1000
    },
    {
        country: 'CA',
        city: 'VAN',
        population: 1000
    },
    {
        country: 'CH',
        city: 'SHANG',
        population: 1000
    },
]


var finalArray=[];
data.forEach(obj => {
    
    let temp = finalArray.find( ob => ob['country'] === obj.country );
if(temp!==undefined){
    temp.population +=obj.population;
} else {
  finalArray.push({country:obj.country,population:obj.population})
}

});

console.log(finalArray)
```